# Passing path as argument to process C#

Tags: c#, process

I have the following code where I am trying to call a C++ console app from C#.  My log file keeps telling me that it can't open the config file.  What is the proper way to write the path as an argument in this case?

```
Process process = new Process();
process.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\\myCapp.exe";
process.StartInfo.Arguments = "C:\\config.txt"; // Put your arguments here
process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
process.Start();
process.WaitForExit();
```

Comment: Does the actual argument string contain spaces?

Comment: I'd recommend a verbatim string, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: Is the process that is trying to execute this code running under an account with permissions to read those paths?

Comment: dasblinkenlight, Yes it does contain spaces.  penguat, tried @, didn't work. Oded, Don't think its a problem of permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Your method is right (just tested this sample). I think problem is in C++ application or in wrong file access.

May be file is opened in C# application and not closed yet?